# Where and how to store URLs in a web module?

Tags: object-oriented, api, web-services

## Situation

I am currently refactoring existing web code. The code currently revolves around a `ServerConfiguration` object. It looks something like this:

```
string UrlBase = "https://myserver.com/api"
string UrlLogin = "/v1/login";
string UrlProjects = "/v1/projects?api_token={0}";

public string GetLoginUrl()
    {
        return UrlBase + UrlLogin;
    }


public string GetProjectsUrl(string apiToken)
    {
        return string.Format(UrlBase + UrlProjects, apiToken);
    }
```

The API this is accessing was made specifically for this app. As such, there is no full CRUD feature set, but only a restricted set of URLs. Most things can only be read, other things can be saved, but on a different link etc.

## Issue

The methods probably should return `Uri` instead of `string`, but my issue is more that I can't find the right place where this information belongs. On one hand, it's nice to have all the links in one place and to have one place to change the server address, should it ever move.

Putting a link into e.g. an own `LoginRequest` object would feel more object-oriented, but it would also duplicate the `UrlBase` part in every request and violate DRY.

## Question

**Where to store URLs?**
My guess is that there are probably way more *small, restricted, dedicated APIs* like this out there than *full feature enterprise CRUD APIs*. So there probably is an established, idiomatic way to store links when objectifying web requests. Maybe there are even several distinct schools of thought. However, as my googling didn't turn up any info regarding this, I don't even know where I stand with my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string UrlLogin = "/v1/login";
string UrlProjects = "/v1/projects?api_token={0}";
```

These are both part of the API definition and can be hardcoded into the client library. Its up to the client to know which endpoint to call when the `Login` method is called

```
string UrlBase = "https://myserver.com/api"
```

This should be passed into the constructor of the client library and stored in a settings file of the app which is using the client.

The client code has no knowledge of where the Api that its calling is deployed, and you probably want to use different urls for the app which is using the client. Your test environment for example might point to `https://myapi.testserver.com` vs `https://myapi.liveserver.com` when deployed to live

eg:

```
public class myClient
{
    private readonly string UrlLogin = "/v1/login";
    private readonly string UrlBase
    public myClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        this.UrlBase = baseUrl;
    }

    public string Login()
    {
        var token = httpclient.Get(this.UrlBase + this.UrlLogin)
        return token;
    }


}

public class myApp()
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseurl"];
        var client = new myClient(url);
        var token = client.Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even thought about it that way around, but that does make more sense. However, what about the 2nd part of the URLs (1st part of your answer) - would you put them all into one object? Or each in a distinct object for each request?

Comment: obvs. you need to combine them with the baseuri at some point, but no i would not have the methods to do that in a separate "serverconfiguration" object

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you like this, but that was a slight misunderstanding. I mean where you would put e.g. the line `string UrlLogin = "/v1/login";`. Would you have all URL extension "constants" together in one object and pass that to different request objects, or would you have the string in the request object itself? (Compared to your example, I have some more code for setting headers, post data etc which probably justifies having an own class per request.)

Comment: I have edited with some examples

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by Ewan, the base URL belongs to the application settings. Even if you don't use different URIs for different environments and even if you're sure the URI won't change (such as, for instance, when you access Amazon S3), it is still a good idea to keep it in the settings, in order to make it explicit which services the application depends on.

From there, the class in charge of the settings should return an `Uri` containing the base URL.

The class you quoted in your question will, as you suggested, return `Uri`s as well. If `UrlLogin` and `UrlProjects` are used only once in code, I'll inline them, i.e. put them directly in the respective methods.

```cs
public Uri GetLoginUrl()
{
    return new Uri(appConfig.BaseUri, "v1/login");
}
```

**Important note:**

Don't deal with `string`s, but rely on `Uri`s and leverage the framework capabilities to do the hard tasks. In this case, the hard task is the proper concatenation of URIs. In your code, **there is a bug**: `https://myserver.com/api` and `/v1/login` should give `https://myserver.com/v1/login`, because this is how URIs work. Your code, however, returns a wrong result, and will be even worse if `/v1/login` is replaced by `v1/login`.

Comment: I don't understand your important note - do you mean there _would_ be a bug if I changed `string` to `Uri` as it is? Because it **is** currently producing the correct result.

Comment: While it is producing the result you expected, the result is only the consequence of the code author not understanding how URIs work. Someone who looks at `/v1/login` recognizes it as an URI *relative to root*. By comparing it with the base URI `https://myserver.com/api`, one would guess there is a mistake (unless `https://myserver.com/v1/login` is a valid URI), which should be fixed by removing the trailing slash. But once the slash is removed, a new issue is discovered.

Comment: So, in short, there is a error in the code, and there is a error in the format of the URIs. Both errors cancel each other, but this doesn't mean the code is good. Instead, you should fix the relative URIs to have a correct format, and rely on the framework to do the concatenation.

Comment: Oohh OK I see your point. As soon as I follow the advice and move the `BaseUri` somewhere else, it's not obvious how the strings are combined and seeing only `/v1/login` one would assume relative to root. While more of a side note to the actual answer, that is something I will change immediately, thanks!